# How to display contact picture using Ionic Contact

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on an app which is in `Ionic 3` and `Angular 4`. 
I am struggling with displaying contact image from Contact Picker of Ionic.

I have used [Ionic Contact](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/) to implement contact picker.

I am able to get the contact's URI but not able to display it on a `img` tag.

Does anyone knows how to display contact image in Ionic 3 ?

Code snippet for component is as below:

```
this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {
      this.photo = contact.photos[0].value;     //  It contains valid photo URI
});
```

My template looks like below:

```
 <ion-avatar><img [src]="photo"></ion-avatar>
```

Comment: Show us the code, html + ts.

Comment: Are you using the Ionic Native wrapper? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/

Comment: @maninak yes I have used that ionic native wrapper

Comment: Have you added your component to the providers of the `NgModule` of your `app.module.ts
`?

Comment: @maninak, yes I have added it. Rest of the app works fine. I am able to pickup a contact and grab the contact object. I also get the URI of contact's photo. But I am struggling with displaying it.

Comment: Have you sanitized the url?

Comment: @SjoerddeWit, Not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trust the url before you can display them because angular has built in xss protection. I think it'll solve your problem. Read about it here: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

You need to do following things:

a. Import DomSanitizer

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

b. Add it's entry in constructor function

```
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        ...
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        ... 
    ){ }
```

c. Use domSanitizer API

```
this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact) => {
  this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(contact.photos[0].value);
});
```

Comment: For me it returns the same input